# Convert if then construct to case_when in the nested data using purrr map2

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Here is my data:

```
vec1 <- c("A", "B")
vec2 <- c("A", "B", "C")

df1 <- structure(list(A = c("X", "Y"), data = list(structure(list(B = c(4L, 9L)), .Names = "B", row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(B = c(5L, 2L, 8L, 2L)), .Names = "B", row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), C = list(c("A", "B"), c("A", "B", "C"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .Names = c("A", "data", "C"))
```

Here is my code:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(data = map2(data, C, ~ if(identical(.y, vec1)) filter(.x, B < 5) else filter(.x, B > 4)))
```

To easily extend the number of conditions, I want to convert the if else construct in the code above to case_when construct. How can I do that?

Comment: I believe you miss the `vec1` in your data.

Comment: @raymkchow My bad, added those now. Thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a `case when`?

Try:

```
m=df1%>%
  mutate(filt=map2(data,match(C,list(vec1,vec2)),
               ~filter_(.x,c("B<=4","B>4")[.y])))

   m
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  A     data             C         filt            
  <chr> <list>           <list>    <list>          
1 X     <tibble [2 x 1]> <chr [2]> <tibble [1 x 1]>
2 Y     <tibble [4 x 1]> <chr [3]> <tibble [2 x 1]>
```

If you want it to be identical to your `df2` just replace the `data` column:

```
df1%>%
      mutate(data=map2(data,match(C,list(vec1,vec2)),
                   ~filter_(.x,c("B<=4","B>4")[.y])))%>%
      identical(df2)
 [1] TRUE
```

If the conditions are too many, you can just create them outside. the ordering of the conditions does matter: The order or the conditions should match the order of the vectors eg:

```
   conditions=c("B>4","B<=4")
   ll=list(vec2,vec1)
   df1%>%
      mutate(data=map2(data,match(C,ll),
                   ~filter_(.x,conditions[.y])))%>%
      identical(df2)
     [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry for the ultra delayed response! filter_ seems to be the deprecated function, will it work in future? If unlikely, do we have a non-deprecated filter_ equivalent/version in dplyr?

Comment: Filter_ is not deprecated,.. it is used to when you need a non-name/symbolic argumate.. eg also mutate_etc...

Comment: Ok, this news mentions something of that sort! https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md. But, it's an elegant answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in this context, I don't know if you can use `case_when`. The documentation states that it returns a vector and does checks to ensure that all elements are the same type (as required by vectors in R). This is as opposed to base `ifelse`, for example, which will coerce to character. Since you are returning a list and not a vector, and so all elements are different type, `case_when` won't work. You will probably need to specify a longer `if` `else if` chain if you have many different `vec` with associated actions that you need to process.

Comment: ok, I like case _hen as I get my head around that construct very easily compared to the if_else chain.

Comment: yeah, in this case you are applying your function to each element of a list, whereas case_when takes an entire vector as input.